# smartphone accepts (max-device-width: x) but not (max-width: x)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want my `@media` apply on smartphones as well as small browser windows.

Therefore I want to use the second `@media` in the below CSS snippet.

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 37em) {
  .max-device-width {
    background: lightgreen;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 37em) {
  .max-width {
    background: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="max-device-width">max-device-width</div>
<div class="max-width">max-width</div>
```

For phones there should be no difference as browsers usually fill the whole screen there.

**Why does my phone accept only the first `@media`?**

EDIT:
As the question seems to be ambiguous:
I am aware of the difference, but i can not understand why a smartphone does not accept both `@media`, once it accepts one of them.

Comment: they are different!!

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz Please be more specific. As i wrote for phone browsers there should be imho no difference, unlike for browsers in a window system.

Comment: see what jasper has written, though it doesn not answer your question, it give you the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the
    `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">`
tag in my html it works but i don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` is the width of the display area (the width of the browser)

`max-device-width` is the max width of the actual screen

Comment: Yes, and in what way does that answer the question?